# listings: highlight LaTeX2e and expl3 code with separate colors

Tags: listings, documentation

I'm planning to write new documentations for my packages, and in particular, this time I wish to improvement the code displaying.

Below is the code I'm currently using for code highlighting. To highlight a command, one would have to add the command name to the `moretexcs` list. This is not very convenient, and more importantly it doesn't seem to work well with expl3 commands with `_` in the command name.

My question is that, how should one configure to make traditional LaTeX2e commands and the new `expl3` commands to have different colors? (Better be automatic and doesn't rely on lists like `moretexcs`)

Thank you in advance for any kind suggestions!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\definecolor{maintheme}{RGB}{70,130,180}
\definecolor{forestgreen}{RGB}{21,122,81}
\definecolor{lightergray}{gray}{0.99}
\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX,
    keywordstyle=\color{maintheme},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{forestgreen}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\rmfamily,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    frame=lines,
    backgroundcolor=\color{lightergray},
    flexiblecolumns=true,
    escapeinside={(*}{*)},
    % numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\scriptsize, stepnumber=1, numbersep=5pt,
    % firstnumber=last,
}
\providecommand{\meta}[1]{$\langle${\normalfont\itshape#1}$\rangle$}
\lstset{moretexcs=%
    {part,parttext,chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,frontmatter,mainmatter,backmatter,tableofcontents,href,
    }
}
\lstnewenvironment{code}%
{\setstretch{1.07}%
\setkeys{lst}{columns=fullflexible,keepspaces=true}%
}{}
\lstnewenvironment{code*}%
{\setstretch{1.07}%
\setkeys{lst}{numbers=left,columns=fullflexible,keepspaces=true}%
}{}

\newcommand{\packageoption}[1]{\texttt{\textcolor{black!67!green}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\commandoption}[1]{\texttt{\textcolor{black!67!cyan}{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{code}
\documentclass[(*\packageoption{options}*)]{class}
\end{code}

\lstinline|\traditionalcommand|

\begin{code}
\mymodule_some_command:nn {} {}
\end{code}

\lstinline|\expl_command:|

\end{document}
```

Comment: Take a look at the package [codehigh](https://ctan.org/pkg/codehigh).

Comment: @projetmbc Thank you for this suggestion. However, `codehigh` doesn't seem to support inline code for now, and also it is not yet as customizable as `listings`.

Answer (score 2):

After exploring the documentation of `listings` for a while, I find the following solution. One still needs to manually add the command names to `moretexcs`, but the colors of LaTeX2 and LaTeX3 commands can be set separately.

[image]

The key is to use `classoffset`, and for LaTeX3 commands, one needs `alsoletter = {_,:}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\definecolor{code-main}{RGB}{70,130,180}
\definecolor{code-expl3}{RGB}{240,50,100}
\definecolor{code-comment}{RGB}{21,122,81}
\definecolor{code-background}{gray}{0.99}
\lstset{
    language = [LaTeX]TeX,
    basicstyle = \ttfamily,
    keywordstyle = \color{code-main},
    commentstyle = \color{code-comment},
    showstringspaces = false,
    breaklines = true,
    frame = lines,
    backgroundcolor = \color{code-background},
    flexiblecolumns = true,
    escapeinside = {(*}{*)},
    alsoletter = {_,:},
    % numbers = left,
    % firstnumber = last,
    numberstyle = \scriptsize\ttfamily,
    stepnumber = 1,
    numbersep = 5pt,
}
\newcommand{\meta}[1]{$\langle${\normalfont\itshape#1}$\rangle$}
\lstset{% LaTeX2 commands
    classoffset = 0,
    texcsstyle =* \color{code-main},
    moretexcs =
      {
        part,parttext,chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,frontmatter,mainmatter,backmatter,tableofcontents,href,
        traditionalcommand
      }
}
\lstset{% LaTeX3 commands
    classoffset = 1,
    texcsstyle =* \color{code-expl3},
    moretexcs =
      {
        mymodule_some_command:nn, expl_command:
      }
}
\lstnewenvironment{code}{\setstretch{1.07}}{}
\lstnewenvironment{code*}{\setstretch{1.07}\lstset{numbers=left}}{}

\newcommand{\packageoption}[1]{\texttt{\textcolor{black!67!green}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\commandoption}[1]{\texttt{\textcolor{black!67!cyan}{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{code}
\documentclass[(*\packageoption{options}*)]{class}
\end{code}

\lstinline|\traditionalcommand|

\begin{code}
\mymodule_some_command:nn {} {}
\end{code}

\lstinline|\expl_command:|

\end{document}
```